# How do you implement multiple nodemail sendMail functions in firestore?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have 2 document references in firestore which trigger a `sendMail` function 'onCreate'. The first one functions perfectly but the 2nd does not. To differentiate between the two `sendMail` functions, I changed the name to `sendMailxxx`. This, I believe, has resulted in the error. The error provided is

> TypeError: transporter.sendMailupfill is not a function

> at exports.sendMailupfill.functions.firestore.document.onCreate

What is the best way to define 2 `sendMail` functions in the same index.js file?

Here with code,

```js
 // Send the transaction email  
 exports.sendMail = functions.firestore.document('Companys/{companyid}/Transaction/{transactionid}').onCreate((snap, context) => {

     const mailOptions = {
         from: 'L App<report@sample.com>', // You can write any mail Address you want this doesn't effect anything,
         to: snap.data().companyemailcf, // This mail address should be filled with any mail you want to read it,
         bcc: 'admin@test.com',
         subject: 'L Fuel , New Tranaction ',
         html: `<h1>Confirmed Transaction</h1>
                                        <p>
                                           
                                           <b>Datetime: </b>${snap.data().datetime}<br>
                                           <b>User: </b>${snap.data().user}<br>
                                           <b>Vehicle: </b>${snap.data().vehicle}<br>
                                           <b>Account: </b>${snap.data().account}<br>
                                           
                                        </p>`
     };



     transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
         if (error) {
             console.log(error);
             return
         }
         console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
     });
 });


 //Send the up-fill email

 exports.sendMailupfill = functions.firestore.document('Companys/{companyid}/Upfill/{upfillid}').onCreate((snap, context) => {



         const mailOptions = {
             from: 'L Fuel App<report@sample.com>',
             to: snap.data().companyemailcf, // 
             subject: 'L Fuel Record, New Tranaction ',
             html: `<h1>Confirmed Bulk Tank Up-fill</h1>
                                        <p>
                                           
                                           <b>Up-fill date: </b>${snap.data().upfilldate}<br>
                                           <b>Up-fill amount: </b>${snap.data().upfillamount}<br>
                                           <b>Up-fill reference: </b>${snap.data().upfillreference}<br>
                                        </p>`
         };



         transporter.sendMailupfill(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
             if (error) {
                 console.log(error);
                 return
             }
             console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
         });
     }


 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't change the name of the call to `transporter.sendMail`.  Just change the name of the exported function.

Comment: Glad it worked.  On Stack Overflow, it's customary to accept helpful answers as correct using the checkmark button on the left.